# Inserting records into database with string restriction?

Tags: sql, string, excel, oracle, vba

I have an issue with SQL insert for oracle database in excel VBA. I realize the excel is not the best method, but due to the nature of the issue I have no choice. The issue is that no VBA variable is able to hold more than 255 characters. The insert statement for the SQL is longer than this. I was able to do the update by breaking it into parts and executing the different fields separately but the same thing can't be done for insert statements. Is there a trick I am unaware of to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance, and notify if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the `string` variable type to itself allowing more than 255 characters by doing this:

```
strText = "This is the first line"
strText = strText & "This is the second line"
```

Note that as you're writing SQL that you need to make sure that the spaces appear in the correct places.